# Room returns IndexOutOfBoundException if there's no result available

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I've defined this function in Room:

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Quer


@Dao
interface PlaceDao {

@Query("SELECT * from place_table")
suspend fun getAllPlaces(): List<Place>

// This query throws IndexOutOfBoundsException 
@Query("SELECT * FROM place_table WHERE masterId IN (:guid)")
suspend fun getPlacesByGuids(guid: List<String>): List<Place>?

}
```

But whenever i call `getPlacesByGuids` passing list of guids against which no place is available in `place_table`, instead of returning empty list or null it throws IndexOutOfBoundException. `getAllPlaces`, on the other hand, seems to work fine even if there's nothing in `place_table` and doesn't result in an exception. Any idea on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Add the version of Room that you're using too.

Comment: I'm using `2.1.0-alpha07`. I just checked they pushed an update just yesterday. I'll try upgrading.

Comment: Just for the sake of making sure, can you try an array (instead of a List)? They seem to use `int[]` here for example: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query